# How to pass a function, list, among others as args to argparse in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, module, arguments, argparse

I have the following script which works, and I'm trying to avoid using `'__main__'` inside the same module:

```
def download():
    urls = \
        [
            'https://ipleak.net/json',
            'https://httpbin.org/get'
        ] * 4

    downloads = asyn.init_download(urls, "json")
    return downloads

def pprint_json(d):
    print(json.dumps(d, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

def multiprocess_list(n_pools, func, list):
    executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(n_pools)
    futures = [executor.submit(func, item) for item in list]
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocess_list(4, pprint_json, download())
```

The `download()` function, as its name depicts, downloads the `urls` asynchronously using `asyncio` and `aiohttp`.

I want to execute `multiprocess_list` from anywhere 'globally':

```
def multiprocess_list(n_pools, func, list):
    executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(n_pools)
    futures = [executor.submit(func, item) for item in list]
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)

def main(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Multiprocessing a list.")
    parser.add_argument("-n", "--n_pools", type=int, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--function", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-l", "--list", required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args(args)

    multiprocess_list(args.n_pools, args.function, args.list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Import the above **module** into any other python file, and perhaps run it like: (doesn't work though)

```
def download():
    urls = \
        [
            'https://ipleak.net/json',
            'https://httpbin.org/get'
        ] * 4

    downloads = asyn.init_download(urls, "json")
    return downloads

def pprint_json(d):
    print(json.dumps(d, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

mp.main(["-n", 4, "-f", pprint_json, "-l", download()])
```

This gives me an error:

> `if not arg_string[0] in self.prefix_chars:
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Hence, pass one argument as a function to be run, another as a list or a function which returns a list like `download()`.

- Can this be done in python?
- If yes, can someone please explain how?
- Is my approach correct or am I completely losing it?

**NB**: My interpreter uses Python3.8 and I'm kind of new to python, please bear with me a little.

Comment: "doesn't work though"? What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Argparse expects a list of strings and may choke on other types. Does it work if you quote the `4`?

```
mp.main(["-n", "4", "-f", pprint_json, "-l", download()])
```

`pprint_json` and the result of `download()` should also be strings for this to work.

This approach of creating a substitute argv is not always crazy, but in your case, why call `main()` to parse the args for you if you've already have them? Why not call `multiprocess_list()` directly with appropriate arguments?

> The reason for using `main()` is because I might add more functions in the future apart from `multiprocess_list()`

Then you can call those directly when invoking the script from Python, instead of creating another argument to select one of them. You can still use `main()` to parse the args from the command line.

> next error `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`

Ah, that wasn't a string either. In that case I don't expect it to work from the command line either. Did you get that much working yet?

You could try something like

```
mp.main(["-n", "4", "-f", "pprint_json", "-l", download()])
```

But then `main()` has to be able to interpret that function name as a function somehow. Maybe something like

```
multiprocess_list(args.n_pools, getattr(foo, args.function), args.list)
```

where `foo` is the module where you keep the selectable functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @gilch, I get the next error `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`. The reason for using `main()` is because I might add more functions in the future apart from `multiprocess_list()` maybe using `parser.add_argument("function", 
                    nargs="?",
                    choices=['multiprocess_list', 'function2', 'function2'],
                    default='multiprocess_list',
                    )`

Comment: @gilch: correct me if I'm wrong: won't this result in a circular import? Question to either of you: could the multiprocess_list file be called using subprocess instead of importing it?

Comment: You actually have a point @mechanical_meat I might be approaching this the wrong way. `subprocess` is somehow what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure how to implement it. `pprint_json()` is just an example, eventually I'm looking to `json_normalize()` or parse html concurrently from all the received data into a dataframe.

Comment: @mechanical_meat `foo` was meant to be a separate module imported by the main one, so no, not circular. If you want to avoid a separate module, you could just put the selectable functions in a dict.